# Get (column, row) index from NumPy array that meets a boolean condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working with a 2D NumPy array. I would like to get the (column, row) index, or (x, y) coordinate, if you prefer thinking that way, from my 2D array that meets a boolean condition.

The best way I can explain what I am trying to do is via a trivial example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> b = a > 4
>>> b
>>> array([[False, False, False],
           [False, False,  True],
           [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

At this point I now have a boolean array, indicating where `a > 4`.

My goal at this point is grab the *indexes* of the boolean array where the value is `True`. For example, the indexes `(1, 2)`, `(2, 0)`, `(2, 1)`, and `(2, 2)` all have a value of True.

My end goal is to end up with a list of indexes:

```
>>> indexes = [(1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Again, I stress the point that the code above is a trivial example, but the application of what I'm trying to do could have arbitrary indexes where `a > 4` and not something based on `arange` and `reshape`.

Comment: Note that the indices you gave are actually (y,x) order, which is also what the answer delivers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`numpy.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
>>> np.column_stack(np.where(b))
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to the answer of @Ashwini Chaudhary, is [numpy.nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> b = a > 4
>>> np.nonzero(b)
(array([1, 2, 2, 2]), array([2, 0, 1, 2]))

>>> np.transpose(np.nonzero(b))
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

EDIT: What is faster. `nonzero` and `where` are essentially equivalent, but `transpose` turns out to be the wrong one here (even though it's [mentioned in the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)):

```
In [15]: N = 5000

In [16]: a = np.random.random((N, N))

In [17]: %timeit np.nonzero(a > 0.5)
1 loops, best of 3: 470 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit np.transpose(np.nonzero(a > 0.5))     # ooops
1 loops, best of 3: 2.56 s per loop

In [19]: %timeit np.where(a > 0.5)
1 loops, best of 3: 467 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit np.column_stack(np.where(a > 0.5))
1 loops, best of 3: 653 ms per loop
```